# Windows Phone Emulator Fails to Start

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am unable to get the Windows Phone 8 Emulator to start.

From Visual Studio 2013 I create a new Windows Phone 8 Application and press F5.

The emulator hangs on the screen below.  When I close the window there is an error listged in Visual Studio saying "Invalid pointer"

[image]

Comment: How long have you waited? Do you have the latest emulators? When 2013 was released the emulators had some issues.

Comment: I have to wait indefinitely. Is there an update somewhere ?  Looking now.

Comment: Today I am facing same problem, have you found any solution?

Comment: Nope.  There appears to be a bug when you have a VPN attached to the computer.  On another machine where I don't have VPN tools the emulator works.